# Line joining in emgucv

Tags: line, emgucv

I have images of the following kind
[image: Output]

I want that small lines which I have encircled using yellow, should be combined to form a single line., i.e. if distance between 2 lines is less than some threshold, they should be joined.

I tried using Dilate command of emgucv, but the unwanted lines also get bold.

Thanx in advance :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your after is the Houghline function I provided a method bellow. By changing these settings you can join lines up and only display those with the strongest characteristics. However, this method may struggle since you have a very very noisy image you may want to look into a better edge detection method first before attempting to find those lines.

### For every line:

```
    private Image<Bgr, Byte> apply_Hough(Image<Bgr, Byte> Input_Image)
    {

        LineSegment2D[] lines = Input_Image.HoughLinesBinary(
          1, //Distance resolution in pixel-related units
          Math.PI / 45.0, //Angle resolution measured in radians.
          50, //threshold
          100, //min Line width
          1 //gap between lines
          )[0]; //Get the lines from the first channel
        Image<Bgr, Byte> lineImage = img.Copy();
        foreach (LineSegment2D line in lines)
            Input_Image.Draw(line, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);

        return Input_Image;
    }
```

Hough lines uses and very advanced voting method in which only the strongest lines will be shown and they should be listed accordingly. So also try using a for loop in replace of the foreach loop to only display the first 6 strongest lines such as this.

### For the 6 strongest lines:

```
    private Image<Bgr, Byte> apply_Hough(Image<Bgr, Byte> Input_Image)
    {

        LineSegment2D[] lines = Input_Image.HoughLinesBinary(
          1, //Distance resolution in pixel-related units
          Math.PI / 90.0, //Angle resolution measured in radians.
          50, //threshold
          100, //min Line width
          1 //gap between lines
          )[0]; //Get the lines from the first channel
        Image<Bgr, Byte> lineImage = img.Copy();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            Input_Image.Draw(lines[i], new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
        }
        return Input_Image;
    }
```

Hope this helps,

Cheers,

Chris